# how to call a Symfony service from my ContainerAwareCommand?

Tags: php, symfony

I do know how to call a `Symfony` service from my `ContainerAwareCommand` a small exemple will be owesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described in detail here:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/console/console_command.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container

A command that implements `ContainerAwareCommand` will have direct access to the service container and you can get/use services as usual.